# Match order of two nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two nested lists:

```
list_a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]

list_b = [[[5, 6], [1, 2] [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]]]
```

I want to re-order list_b so that the order of each nested list, i.e. [[5, 6], [1, 2], [3, 4]], matches what is in list_a:

```
list_b = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

In reality these lists are populated with thousands of float data points instead of integers and contain 25 embedded lists each instead of the 3 here, but their shape is always the same.  The order that I want (list_a) is always the same, and list_b is always shuffled in the same way.

How do I get what I need?  So far I've gotten to the sort function, and I've tried to use it with indexing to get what I need since I know what the indices are and what they should be.  But I can't wrap my head around how to design a key that will deal with looping over each nested list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To add context:

Each array holds EEG data in the shape of Trials x Electrodes x Data Points.  I want to subtract two of such arrays to get an array of the diff between them, but first I have to make sure that the "electrodes" line up.  The output I was getting revealed that the order of 'electrodes' in each array was not the same, so the wrong electrodes were being subtracted from each other.

I started by figuring out how to get a list of indices for each electrode on a small example, like so:

```
chan_order = ['Fp1', 'Fp2', 'F3', 'F7', 'F4', 'F8']
wanted_order = ['Fp1', 'Fp2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F7', 'F8']
new_indices = [chan_order.index(x) for x in wanted_order]
```

Then I applied this approach using sort:

```
new_order = sorted(chan_order, key=lambda x: wanted_order.index(x))
```

This gets me what I wanted on a simplified example, but I don't know how to apply that when the data is actually:

```
[[[1.02, 2.22, .90, 2.50...], [2.05, 1.11, 2.34, .80...], [1.02, 2.22, .90, 2.50...]]]
```

Each float here is the amplitude value for a given time point, so the values fluctuate a lot.  Each list of floats represents the recordings from a single electrode.  The lists of lists represents trials, of which there are many.  So in the above example, we can imagine that

```
[1.02, 2.22, .90, 2.50]
```

is from electrode 'Fp1', and the remaining are 'Fp2' and 'F3'.  The problem is that one of the arrays will always have the order 'Fp1', 'Fp2', 'F3', while the second is shuffled e.g. Fp1, F3, Fp2.  This information is stored in a separate 1D list of channel names, so I know the channel order of each array.

Comment: Please provide code for what you have done so far.

Comment: Based on what you've said, the easiest solution is going to be `list_b = list_a`, possibly with a `copy.deepcopy` thrown in for good measure. Why do you insist on sorting the existing list if you know exactly what you want the result to be?

Comment: Done my best to clarify this problem in the edit.

Comment: If all the elements are just floats, how do you know which ones belong to which electrodes? Please provide an example of what (a portion of) the array *actually* looks like. I bet what you actually want is a dictionary but I can't figure out what they keys and values would be.

Comment: Added some actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, let's say the order is always fixed and thus you need to programmatically reorder each element of the nested list.

Here's some reference and toy data:

`order          ['D','A','B','C']
desired_order   ['A','B','C','D']`

`data = [[1.4,2.9,0.5,1.1],[2.2,1.8,7,0.01]]`

Define a function that will crawl a list of lists and reorder / return each element of the nested list. You might even be able to combine this with your "new_order" approach above to remove the "hard coded" element of the function.

`def reorder(lst):
    ret = []
    for i in lst:
        ord = [i[1],i[2],i[3],i[0]]  #this needs to change depending upon the actual order
        ret.append(ord)
    return ret`

`d2 = reorder(data)`

`d2
[[2.9, 0.5, 1.1, 1.4], [1.8, 7, 0.01, 2.2]]`

Comment: This looks like it will work splendidly, I did not think of [i[1],i[2],i[3],i[0]] as a possibility. Thank you for your help, I know my description was not easy to digest!

Answer (score 1):

In your toy model, I'm able to simply do

```
for i in list_b:
    i.sort()
```

and go from:

```
list_b = [[[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]], [[3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6]]]
```

to:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

```
>>> list_a == list_b
True
```

I suspect it's not that easy, and the approach may break with your floats.

Comment: It will break, the values in each cell fluctuate widely and are not ordinal.

Comment: Understood - especially given your point about amplitude fluctuation. In the list that you are trying to modify, will each element consistently be in the same order? As in, will it always be D, B, C, A and you'll always want A, B, C, D?

Comment: From what I can tell yes, that is a safe assumption.